# please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, thread-safety, osx-yosemite

I trying to install pthreads on Mac Os X.
When I execute:

```
sudo pecl install pthreads
```

I get error:

> checking checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
>   ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure' failed

So the question is how to recompile php with ZTS enabled for OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you don't recompile OS X native `php`. Instead build and install new thread-safe version to different location.

If you use homebrew you should install it with `-with-thread-safety` option.

If you prefer to build it manually add `--enable-maintainer-zts` option to `configure` script.

Comment: Please, can you provide step by step instruction?

Comment: I just went through this, I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tam5/2e06063c17de7e200040) for this specific setup.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Homebrew is not supporting the thread-safe version anymore: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/php.rb#L56